# Log Based metrics preview displays but absent in metrics explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, log-based-metrics

I have created some log based metrics in GCP and confirmed using the `Preview Logs` that they are valid (getting green bubbles with numbers in them).

However, when trying to view these in the metrics explorer, they are inactive (I need to toggle "Show only active resources and metrics" for the log based metric to show up) -- and then after toggling it on, sure enough, there is no time series to display.

What could be the problem?

Comment: try to review this [stock overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386595/create-distribution-metric-with-logs-based-metrics-and-regex?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this sorted, but it's a top result when I was working through this.
In my case I was using string values in a **distribution** type log based metric. So it looks fine in the Preview Logs, and the labels all look fine, but when you send data through you get nothing in metrics explorer.
Creating a new **counter** type metric worked fine.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I have two almost identical log based metrics. Both are counter, one is checking for one jsonPayload.message and other for another. Simple difference, two log based metrics. One pop in metrix explorer after an hour, second is still not viisble after hours!

GCP has it buggy.. for a long time